# Local gems for rails outside of gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

We've got a developer who gets errors with a gem while using zsh, but the rest of us would still like to use the gem.  Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237055/how-to-use-gems-not-in-a-gemfile-when-working-with-bundler), add the following code to the bottom of your gemfile.

```
gemfile_local = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'Gemfile.local')
if File.readable?(gemfile_local)
  puts "Loading #{gemfile_local}..." if $DEBUG
  instance_eval(File.read(gemfile_local))
end
```

Have each of the developers who want to use the problem gem to add it to their Gemfile.local.  This is the most elegant solution I have found for using gems you don't want to commit to version control.  Don't forget to add Gemfile.local to your .gitignore.