# How can I specify user-specific gems for my RoR app?

Tags: ruby, gemfile

I am an odd-man out in that I use Windows for my client so in order to get Growl notifications, I use `ruby_gntp`. How can I define this gem for me alone and not pollute my co-workers' Gemfiles? This is important because they'll get exceptions about the notifications not going through when it is not relevant for them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use gems not in a Gemfile when working with bundler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237055/how-to-use-gems-not-in-a-gemfile-when-working-with-bundler)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Bundler documentation, you should be able to specify a platform for Windows only:

```
gem 'ruby_gntp', :platforms => :mswin
```

Comment: In my case, the server is running on Linux, only my client is on Windows so this is not helpful.